# Can Visual Studio 2008 Projects be converted to a newer Visual studio versions?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to convert my visual studio 2008 projects to VS2019 but getting incompatible errors. I also tried earlier versions like 2012, 2015 and got the same thing. Is this even possible?

Comment: What type of projects are they?

Comment: @TrevorBrooks some are windows and some are web projects.

Comment: Can you show what the errors are exactly?